# Local Aliases for Variables in Python (especially in the context of a lambda)

Tags: python, lambda

I often find that when processing a list, I end up with lambdas that are hard to read because they involve indexing into an array with literal constants where the meaning of the constant is hard to deduce.  Something like:

```
result = list(map(lambda p: (p[0] - altX) / math.cos(p[1]), list_))
```

though typically more convoluted.  I'd like to assign temporary names to these list elements, something like:

```
x,y = p
(x - altX) / math.cos(y)
```

Is there any elegant way of doing this?

The best solution I've found, so far, is to simply create a stand alone function (i.e., using def).  But this often feels heavy weight and requires context to be passed as extra arguments.

```
def Helper(p, altX):
    x, y = p
    (x - altX) / math.cos(y)
```

The clumsiness of this approach is amplified by the difficulty of passing the extra "context" variable(s) to the function using `map`.  For example,

```
result = list(map(func, list_, 1))
```

is not syntactically correct.  I'd like something like:

```
result = list(lambda p as (x,y): (x - altX) / math.cos(y), list_)
```

or

```
result = list(lambda p: with p as x,y: (x - altX) / math.cos(y), list_)
```

or

```
result = list(lambda p: using p[0] as x: using p[1] as y: (x - altX) / math.cos(y), list_)
```

Comment: In Python 2, you *could* write `lambda (x,y): ...`, and the argument would be automatically unpacked into `x` and `y`. I kind of miss that, to be honest.

Comment: I would consider using a list comprehension instead, `[(x - altX) / math.cos(y) for x, y in list_]`.

Comment: If you did your `def Helper():` *inside* the calling function, it could access `altX` directly as a nonlocal variable, without needing to somehow pass it as a parameter.

Comment: Keep in mind, too, that if `list_` isn't "naturally" defined as a list of tuples, but you defined it using `zip` and a pair of lists, then you can simply write `map(lambda x, y: ..., l1, l2)` instead of `map(lambda p:, zip(l1, l2))`.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, using [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap):

```py
import math
from itertools import starmap

lst = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
altX = -1

result = list(starmap(lambda x, y: (x - altX) / math.cos(y), lst))
print(result)
```

Prints:

```
[-4.805995923444762, -6.11954262586559, 6.248891559570646]
```

Comment: I had just remembered `starmap` was a thing and was editing my answer to include it. Guess I won't bother now...  :)

Comment: @chepner But honestly, I'd use normal list-comprehension, as you stated in the comment :)

Answer (score 2):

You can get a bit functional and define *another* function that does nothing but unpack `p` to use as the arguments for the first function:

```
result = list(map(lambda p: (lambda x,y: (x - altX) / math.cos(y))(*p), list_))
```

(Basically, your helper function defined with a lambda expression in-place rather than before you call `map`.)

---

(Or use `itertools.starmap`, which I forget exists.... Seriously, nobody upvote this without upvoting https://stackoverflow.com/a/77896743/1126841 as well.)

Comment: I'd use the list comprehension as stated in your comment.

Comment: Is this correct or are you missing a `map` on your list call? ie `list(map(...))`?

Comment: That would make more sense, wouldn't it...

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use good old comments as in

```
result = list(map(
    lambda p: (p[0] - altX) / math.cos(p[1]),   # some useful comments here
    list_))                                     # the actual list
```

I mean, not really an answer but the obvious solution, imo.

Answer (score 1):

You could repack the data  differently using `zip` before passing to `map`: ie

```
results = list(map(lambda x, y: (x - altX) / math.cos(y), *zip(*lst)))
```

---

Using the example from @Andrej we get:

```
[-4.805995923444762, -6.11954262586559, 6.248891559570646]
```

Answer (score 1):

Often, replacing `map(lambda x: ..., ...)` with a generator expression and `list(map(lambda x: ..., ...))` with a list comprehension results in more Pythonic code:

```
result = [(x - altX) / math.cos(y) for x, y in list_]
```

Alternatively, you can define your helper function as a nested function, which makes it a closure, and you can still use the context without passing it:

```
def _helper(p):
    x, y = p
    return (x - altX) / math.cos(y)

result = list(map(_helper, list_))
```

This approach is more readable if when your lambda gets too complicated.

You can also use `functools.partial`:

```
from functools import partial

def reusable_helper(p, alt_x):
    x, y = p
    return (x - alt_x) / math.cos(y)

# ...

result = list(map(partial(reusable_helper, alt_x=altX), list_)
```

This is particularly useful if the helper function can be reused in other parts of the code base.